# Network printer configuration

Tags: networking, kubuntu, printing, cups-lpd

After several attempts I cannot reach the network printer of my local network.
I am using Kubuntu 22.04.

The printer cannot be found in the KDE printer manager, so I tried so add it manually using the CUPS server and the network interface http://localhost:631/admin/ but the authentication there always fails (in spite of adding myself to the lpadmin group).
I also want to add that the local network is protected by a http proxy server.

I am a little bit confused and would appreciate any help, sorry if I misused some terms I am a beginner...
Thank you,
Louis

Comment: Did you logout/login after adding yourself to the `lpadmin` group? Groups are setup at login, or, for a single process tree by `newgrp` command.

Comment: Hello thanks for your reply! Yes I have tried to logout/login and it does not change anything. When I input my ID/pwd on CUPS it asks me to input it again and again.